Evap cooler Honeywell CL512 glue smell since new
How can I get rid of glue smell from this new unit? Dry air or humid air? Any tips are appreciated.

"Since new" is how long?  A week?  A year?

I bought it about a week ago

I would give any parts that touch water a good cleaning.
